# azure AD: The reply url specificed in the request does not match the reply url configured in the application

Tags: firebase, flutter, azure-active-directory

I want to make login with microsoft possible for my app (with firebase)
Im using this package https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth_oauth/versions

```dart
User user = await FirebaseAuthOAuth().openSignInFlow("microsoft.com",
        ["email openid"], {'tenant': 'my-id'});
    ;
```

I have added my app in azure AD, i get this when i use my signin function.

[image]

I see something about a redirect URL in azure AD but i dont know what it is supossed to be.
The firebase docs say this:

`When registering apps with these providers, be sure to register the *.firebaseapp.com domain for your project as the redirect domain for your app. (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/microsoft-oauth)`

but i dont know where to do that (also is it just *.firebaseapp.com or does * need to be something?)

Any help?

Comment: see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GivoZ.png

Comment: You need to configure the reply url in the Azure portal.

Comment: @CarlZhao what am i supossed to put there? just doing *.firebaseapp.com does not work.

Comment: The reply url you configured in the code must be the same as that configured in the portal!

Comment: i did not add a reply url to my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a general solution to the problem of **not match**:

When you visit the application url , you will be redirected to the login page. Decode the authorization request URL, you will find redirect_uri, copy the value of redirect_uri and paste it into the azure portal, and try again.

[image]

For the redirect URL, it should start with `https`, if you need to start with http, you must configure it as `http://localhost`.

Comment: https%3A%2F%2Fshare-files-26506.firebaseapp.com%2F__%2Fauth%2Fhandler            this is the part in the url that you mean right? what should i put in azure portal now?

Comment: @venum  Decode the url and paste it into the Azure portal.

Comment: works! sadly its not getting stored in firebase